# What are some terms for "spoiled crop"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Are there specific terms for crop that has been ruined in some way? I'd especially enjoy a word/phrase for produce/crop that has over-ripened or rotted away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no specific terms for *rotten* crops, but you can use many of the synonyms of rotten.  One common term is *spoiled* to indicate the crop is no longer nutritive.

> With the men off to war, many of the farms' crops went unharvested, and lay **spoiled** and **rotting** under the blistering summer sun.

If the crops have been destroyed by disease, you can instead use *blighted*

> The pestilence spread rapidly through the fields, leaving large swaths of **blighted** crops in its wake.

As with most words, it can be used figuratively:

> But Ahab's glance was averted; like a **blighted** fruit tree he shook, and cast his last, cindered apple to the soil.

As in the above example, a *pestilence* is a plague-like disease that can be used with agriculture.  You can also use *withered* to describe crops that are damaged and dying and generally unusable.

*Infestation* is another, although more often used with things like insects rather than bacteria or fungi.

Not related to crops, but certain foods, particularly those that are fatty or oily, can go *rancid*.

> She rummaged around his refrigerator to try and find something to eat, but all she found was a wide assortment of condiments and a stick of **rancid** butter, that must have been left there by the previous tenant.

Other foods, such as milk, can *sour*, and still others (bread, fruit, cheese, etc.) can be covered by fungi and become *moldy*.  This also can apply to some crops that are susceptible to fungal diseases.

Comment: Thanks Andrew! I really like 'blighted,' especially its metaphoric usage. And yes, I'd like to be as descriptive as possible, as I'm looking for a vivid word to use in a poem ( I don't mind if it gets disgusting :P). I was hoping that there'd be certain words, perhaps used in farming contexts, to delineate the different ways in which crop might spoil. I don't mind if it's slang.

Comment: Also I'm intrigued by how quickly you came up with that wonderful example from Moby Dick. Is it a famous line?

Comment: @user475924  I searched Google for "use blighted in a sentence" and then scanned through some of the pages of results.

Comment: @user475924  I've added a couple more, but I don't know of any slang terms.  I was thinking of words like *purulent* which refers to pus-filled boils, usually on animals but possible on vegetation.